# More elegant way to test mapreduce streaming job locally?

Tags: python, hadoop, testing, mapreduce

I have a mapreduce job writing in Python. Before I put it on EMR I'd like to test it locally.

Currently the only way I know to test is to run the command:

`cat input_file | python mapper.py | sort -k 1,1 | python reducer > output_file`

But the pipe is a little scary to me cause if anything breaks in it I wouldn't know (other than check the exit code of this command).

Is there a more elegant/pythonic way to run the mapreduce and check it runs successfully (so I can catch a specific exception and handle it)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One obvious way would be to test your code in a local Hadoop framework. 
For instance, you may use packaged Hadoop cluster in a VM, provided by [Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-5.html) or [Hortonworks](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/).